Обработка звуковой дорожки в реальном времени и поиск заданного аудиофрагмента на C#
Мне нужно написать код на C#, который в реальном времени будет брать звуковую дорожку из определенной программы (например, аудио из видеоплеера или игры) и анализировать ее, чтобы найти заранее загруженный аудиофрагмент (например, в формате MP3).
Не нашел толковой информации по тому, какие библиотеки или методы лучше всего использовать. Буду очень благодарен, если поможете

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio
